# Change the background color with a sticky element

Tags: jquery, html, css, colors, sticky

I would like to change the body color background on scroll with a sticky element.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: lightblue;
}

.blue-container {
  height: 70vh;
}

.blue {
  height: 40vh;
  position: sticky;
  width: 70%;
  top: 0;
  background: blue;
  margin: auto;
}

.pink {
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  width: 70%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  background: pink;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class='blue-container'>
  <div class='blue'></div>
</div>

<div class='pink'> When I touch the blue bloc, I would like the 'body background' change into an other color (for exemple : orange)</div>
```

Here's my [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/613odm7n/6/) to understand what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could calculate the empty space between `blue` div and `pink` div with a difference (`$('.blue-container').height() - $('.blue').height()`), then when the document scrolled till that misure you know that the pink div has touch the blue one.

```js
$(function(){

  $(window).scroll(function(){
    var margin = $('.blue-container').height() - $('.blue').height();
    if($(this).scrollTop()>=margin){
        $("body").addClass("orange")
    } else{
     $("body").removeClass("orange")
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  background:lightblue;}

.blue-container {
 height:70vh;
}

.blue {
 height:40vh;
 position:sticky;
 width:70%;
 top:0;
 background:blue;
 margin:auto;
}

.pink {
 height:500px;
 position:relative;
 width:70%;
 margin-right:auto;
 margin-left:auto;
 background:pink;
  text-align:center;
}

.orange{
  background:orange
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='blue-container'>
  <div class='blue'></div>
</div>

<div class='pink'> When I touch the blue bloc, I would like the 'body background' change into an other color (for exemple : orange)</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if you can to that in pure CSS, but here is a vanillaJS solution:

- We trigger an event on scroll
- We check blue's bottom position and pink's top position
- If they are equals, we trigger the logic.

```js
var blue = document.querySelector('.blue')
var pink = document.querySelector('.pink')
var onTouch = false;

//http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/DOM-Level-3-Events/html/DOM3-Events.html#event-type-scroll
function onScrollEventHandler(ev) {
    var bottom = blue.getBoundingClientRect().bottom
    var top = pink.getBoundingClientRect().top
    // we set
    if (bottom == top && !onTouch) {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'orange' 
        onTouch = true
    }
    // we reset
    if (bottom != top && onTouch) {
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'lightblue' 
      onTouch = false
    }
} 

var el=window;
if(el.addEventListener)
    el.addEventListener('scroll', onScrollEventHandler, false);   
else if (el.attachEvent)
    el.attachEvent('onscroll', onScrollEventHandler);
```

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  background:lightblue;}

.blue-container {
 height:70vh;
}

.blue {
 height:40vh;
 position:sticky;
 width:70%;
 top:0;
 background:blue;
 margin:auto;
}

.pink {
 height:500px;
 position:relative;
 width:70%;
 margin-right:auto;
 margin-left:auto;
 background:pink;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class='blue-container'>
  <div class='blue'></div>
</div>

<div class='pink'> When I touch the blue bloc, I would like the 'body background' change into an other color (for exemple : orange)</div>
```

This code is a work in progress. All inputs are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [intersection observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) to detect when enough `.pink` element is inside the viewport touch the `.blue` element:

```js
const body = document.querySelector('body');
const blue = document.querySelector('.blue');
const target = document.querySelector('.pink');

const getHeight = (el) => el.getBoundingClientRect().height;

// get the threshold in which enough of the pink elment would be inside the viewport to touch the blue element
const threshold = (window.innerHeight - getHeight(blue)) / getHeight(target);

const options = {
  rootMargin: '0px',
  threshold
};

let prevRatio = 0;

const handleIntersect = (entries, observer) => {
  entries.forEach(function(entry) {
    // if going up (above the previous threshold & above the threshold
    if (entry.intersectionRatio >= threshold && entry.intersectionRatio > prevRatio) {
      body.classList.add('body--intersected');
    } else {
      body.classList.remove('body--intersected');
    }

    prevRatio = entry.intersectionRatio;
  });
}

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(handleIntersect, options);

observer.observe(target);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: lightblue;
}

.body--intersected {
  background: pink;
}

.blue-container {
  height: 70vh;
}

.blue {
  height: 40vh;
  position: sticky;
  width: 70%;
  top: 0;
  background: blue;
  margin: auto;
}

.pink {
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  width: 70%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  background: pink;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class='blue-container'>
  <div class='blue'></div>
</div>

<div class='pink'> When I touch the blue bloc, I would like the 'body background' change into an other color (for exemple : orange)</div>
```